# ボタンクリックしたら、HTMLの指定タグ(id)範囲のみ画面キャプチャしたい

Tags: javascript, php

ボタンクリックしたら、HTMLの指定タグ(id)範囲のみ、「JavaScript」か「PHP」で画面キャプチャしたいです。

HTMLの指定タグ(id)範囲から、画面位置を割り出し、そのサイズを取得して、画像で画面キャプチャすることは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS ネイティブな方法でスクリーンショットを取ることはできないと思いますが、指定の HTML 要素を Canvas に描画して、それを画像データに変換することで、ページの一部を画像として取ることは可能です。 Javascript ライブラリの [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) がその用途に適しています。コードは以下のようになるはずです。

サンプル: 指定セレクタ('#target_id'等)の要素を画像にして `post_screenshot.php` にポスト

```
function screenshot( selector) {
    var element = $(selector)[0];
    html2canvas(element).then(function(canvas) {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
        $.post("post_screenshot.php", {dataurl: imgData}, function (res_code) {
            window.alert( res_code);
        });   
    });
}
```

(※上のコードは、 GitHub 版でなければ動きません。)

サーバ側では、受け取った JSON データの `dataurl` 値を Base64 でデコードする形になります。

---

**追記: (2/3)**

[こちらの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/5862/4978)に、動くコードを投稿しました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。出来るんですね。大変参考になりましたー